# Yii2 : Joining child table to two parent tables

Tags: yii, yii2

I have two parent tables and 1 child table in this format -

A - a_id, a_name (parent)
B - b_id, b_name (parent)
C - c_id, *a_id, b_id*

- aid and bid are foreign keys in table C.

I am trying to create a dataProvider starting from Model A, and want to join C to the picture such that the code looks like

$query->joinWith([B,**A&B.C**]

But I don't know how to make C join to both A and B for the given query using Yii2 standards. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You want to get all Bs related with an A through C?

Comment: a good practice is to prepare the sql first and then convert it according to Yii2 standards.

Comment: @gmc I want to include C in the dataprovider using A.joinWith such that C.b_id = B.b_id. I have been able to correctly do that using the where operator. But it shows the wrong number of records.

Comment: What would you want to include C? As far as I know, C is only a junction table to relate A with B. For such cases, take a look at [viaTable](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#viaTable()-detail)

Answer (score 0):

To make `JOIN` with Yii2 through multiple `DataProvider` models you can use simple:

```
$results = $tableADataProvider->joinWith(['cRelation.bRelation')
                              ->where([...]);
```

And of course in `A` table `DataProvider` you need to have relation to `C` table, in this example `cRelation` and in `C` table `DataProvider` you need to have relation to `B` table `bRelation`.

Also to mention IF you don't use any column from tables `B` and `C` in `WHERE` clause, but just you want to retrieve results from `B` then it's much better to use `$tableADataProvider->with([...])` which fetches data trough another query. This way even if they are pivot tables, you will get correct count of Table `A`.

**Worthy to note that you probably didn't get correct count (count that you wanted) if table(s) is/are pivot table(s).**

*(Pivot table is a table that have more than 1 record that have same unique key of other table)*